# .NET MAUI Recurrent Background Job that runs few times a day

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, background-process, maui

I would like to have a background job to run like 2-3 times a day, but even less it's ok. It's just a quick api call to my server, it doesn't need to update the UI, infact I prefer that it runs when the app is not in the foreground, but that's another topic.

I've read that latests versions of Android and iOS or even manifacturers restrict the app but I don't need these task to be at certain time precisely.
I'm not sure if I should use the JobScheduler or WorkManager for Android and the BackgroundFetch or BackgroundTask for iOS.

Let's say the task should run 3 times a day so every 8 hours roughly.
The thing is that a user might not open the app again so the task should be scheduled to be recurrent, maybe every time it runs it could schedule another one, but if one fails that line could never be reached.

I don't need to support old operating system version, only iOS 15+ and Android api 30+.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: The amount of work required to be done is unrealistic to be put in one answer. Check this to get basic idea: https://github.com/shinyorg/shiny

Comment: @H.A.H. oh well thanks i will use that package directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple is strict about hardware resources occupied by App, not to mention App in the background state. When App enter the background state, it will soon be suspended by the OS, unless you apply for permission from OS. Only several modes could be allowed to run in the background, see the following picture

[image]

You want a background cron job which is not allowed in iOS.

For Andriod, you know we could use WorkManager or JobSchedule. Here are some documents that you could refer to:

[Getting Started With WorkManager](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/getting-started-workmanager/)

[Android Job Scheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/android-job-scheduler)

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Well if apple is so strict i can't even be sure that the job will run at least once or twice a day, i will just reconsider this feature and tell user to open the app for the syncronization after they have done something offline. This seems too much of an hassle.

Comment: Yes you are right. Apple set restrictions for the background use. Only several modes could run in the background. for 'syncronization', did you mean fetch some data from the Internet?

Comment: Yes i call an api, i post the data that changed when they were offline and i get some data back that i will store in a database.

Comment: btw here's the official explanation, this is literally not possible on iOS, only in android
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/685525

Comment: yes, I cannot agree more.

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT Can you take a look at my answer and tell me what it's not working? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this, but I can't get it to work.

Add this to info.plist.

Tells the app to allow background fetch and background processing.

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
  <array>
    <string>fetch</string>
    <string>processing</string>
  </array>
```

Tells the app to allow the tasks to be performed.

```
<key>BGTaskSchedulerPermittedIdentifiers</key>
  <array>
    <string>com.yourappname.upload</string>
    <string>com.yourappname.refresh</string>
  </array>
```

Register these as variables in your AppDelegate.

```
    public static string UploadTaskId { get; } = "com.yourappname.upload";
    
    public static string RefreshTaskId { get; } = "com.yourappname.refresh";
```

Register this in your AppDelegate FinishedLaunching method.

```
    BGTaskScheduler.Shared.Register(UploadTaskId, null, task => HandleUpload(task as BGProcessingTask));
    BGTaskScheduler.Shared.Register(RefreshTaskId, null, task => HandleAppRefresh(task as BGAppRefreshTask));
```

Now it should call this method every once in a while.

```
private void HandleUpload(BGTask task)
    {
        SentrySdk.CaptureMessage("BGTaskScheduler HandleUpload = " + "yes");

        ProcessData(); //or something like this
        task.SetTaskCompleted(true);
    }
```

It should also call this method every once in a while.

```
private void HandleAppRefresh(BGAppRefreshTask task)
    {

        SentrySdk.CaptureMessage("BGTaskScheduler HandleAppRefresh = " + "yes");

        task.ExpirationHandler = () =>
        {            
            var refresh = new BGAppRefreshTaskRequest(RefreshTaskId);
            BGTaskScheduler.Shared.Submit(refresh, out NSError refreshError);

            if (refreshError != null)
                //Console message
        };

        HandleUpload(task);
    }
```

I even call this method from my ProcessData() and DidEnterBackground override methods.

```
private void ScheduleUpload()
    {
        SentrySdk.CaptureMessage("BGTaskScheduler ScheduleUpload = " + "yes");

        Console.WriteLine("ScheduleUpload");

        var startDate = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10);

        var upload = new BGProcessingTaskRequest(UploadTaskId)
        {
            RequiresNetworkConnectivity = true,
            RequiresExternalPower = false,
            EarliestBeginDate = (NSDate)startDate
        };

        BGTaskScheduler.Shared.Submit(upload, out NSError error);

        var refresh = new BGAppRefreshTaskRequest(RefreshTaskId);
        BGTaskScheduler.Shared.Submit(refresh, out NSError refreshError);

        if (error != null)
            Console.WriteLine($"Could not schedule BGProcessingTask: {error}");
        if (refreshError != null)
            Console.WriteLine($"Could not schedule BGAppRefreshTask: {refreshError}");
    }
```

Comment: sorry for the late answer! wow thank you a lot i will try this definetely!

Comment: I can confirm that HandleUpload is getting called every once in a while. The ProcessData() function sets some flags in my database, so I don't see that working. I'll continue to work on this. Encouraging that HandleUpload is getting called. This is verified in .Net Maui 8.0.3 .Net 8 iOS app targeting 17.0 with support for 16.1. It also worked in my .Net 7 app targeting 16.1 with support for 15.4.

Comment: welp i forgot about this, i ended up using firebase push notifications because i needed more precise updates

Comment: Well not when the app is closed no. I ended up sending push notifications trough firebase, when the user tap the notification the app open and will ask the server for updated data. I don't even remember why i asked this to be honest.